# Google maps api v3 - ReferenceError: wd is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps API v3, I keep getting this error: `ReferenceError: wd is not defined.`

I see the same error in IE11, but it keeps going and creates a map.  Firefox doesn't do this.  When debugging, it gets to the main.js :22, line 38, col 166

> FileName: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/17/9/main.js line 52 > eval
>   Message: wd is not defined
>   Stack: "Kr@https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/17/9/main.js line 52 >

Any ideas what I need to tweak to fix this?

Comment: Please provide your code (perferably a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and if possible a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Links won't help future readers.

Comment: I know but if I can solve this, I'll post what I messed up.

Comment: I am getting same error. Is there anybody help?

Comment: Oddly, I upgraded to FF 31 and problem is GONE.  Would still like to know what I did wrong.

Comment: I found why. I guess you are using gmap on tab or modal, aren't you?

Comment: No, normal div inside table.  What did you think was reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, I believe that when the Maps API detects an error in your javascript, it sends back this error code and stops it's processing. It seems to have some kind of timeout as well, because once you fix your error, it will keep sending this error for a little while, perhaps a few minutes.

I've also found that closing the tab/window and then going back to the page seems to clear the error right away.

Comment: Kinda hard to debug and fix the code if it doesn't tell you much.  Version 3 is SOOO much more Picky than Version 2 was, which worked on every browser easily.